# WebDriver - Chrome - list of excludeSwitches

Tags: webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Where I can find a full list of excludeSwitches with descriptions ?

As for now I found only: 'enable-automation', 'load-extension', 'disable-popup-blocking' but without descriptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option in the web driver instructs it to not pass particular command-line switches that are normally used when starting a new instance of Chrome, as such there are no specific switches which are applicable.

Your best bet is to use programs like Process Explorer to see what switches the Web Driver uses to launch chrome and study them. Here is a [list of all switch](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) that are accepted by Chrome, this is not an official source but it's the most comprehensive one I could find and the page is auto-generated from Chromium source code. There are also descriptions for most of the interesting switches.